# Adobe Air video player blank video on iPad

Tags: ipad, apache-flex, air

Any idea why this simple piece of code wont work on iPad mobile? This works great on Android tablets, the desktop version, web version, etc. On iPad, the video is blank

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- controls\videoplayer\VideoPlayerEvent.mxml-->
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">


    <s:VideoPlayer 
        source="rtmp://fmsexamples.adobe.com/vod/mp4:_cs4promo_1000.f4v"
        width="500" height="500" x="500" y="500"
        loop="true" />
 </s:Application>
```

Comment: What are you using as your RTMP server, and what is your media encoded as? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/stream-ondemand-flash-and-ios.html

Comment: iOS doesn't playback h.264 encoded mp4s or f4vs through the standard Flex `VideoPlayer`. Only ways you can play those back are through `StageWebView` and `StageVideo`

Comment: Thanks guys -  you are both right. Just add your comments as answers and I'll accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from my comment:

iOS doesn't playback of h.264 encoded mp4s or f4vs through the standard Flex `VideoPlayer`. Only ways you can play those back are through `StageWebView` and `StageVideo`