# AIR: playing vH264 on IOS. How to do it using StageWebView or StageVideo?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have found that post:
[Adobe Air video player blank video on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132324/adobe-air-video-player-blank-video-on-ipad)

That tells that H264 video could be played on IOS using StageWebView and StageVideo

Is there any existing sample for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check info here

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html

try to use this example http://01am.co.uk/blog/stagevideo-ios-air

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the key code you need.  This is how you do h.264 on stageVideo in air for ios.  You set a rectangle to show it - viewPort.

```
ncMain = new NetConnection();
ncMain.connect(null);
nsMain = new NetStream(ncMain);
nsMain.client = this;
svMain = stage.stageVideos[0];
svMain.attachNetStream(nsMain);
svMain.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0,1024,768);
```

After this code it should be regular netStream commands like:

```
nsMain.play("myVideo.mp4");
```

gotoandlearn.com has a tutorial with some code for stageVideo.